# How to visualize an evolution of a distribution in time with python?

Tags: python, statistics, data-visualization, distribution

Suppose you have a record of distribution for each day in some period. For example, some distribution which depends on a parameter which evolves over time. Suppose we have dozens or hundreds of days. How would you visualize the change of this distribution? I want the plot to contain as much info as possible.

One way I could think of is: proxy the density function and plot these curves's evolution in 2D. It will be some form of homotopy: the initial distribution converging to the final with some smooth step. Of course here I assume smoothness.

Thanks for your help.

The question is theoretical in nature but I am aiming for python realization so implementations or suggestions for libraries are also welcome.

Comment: how about characterizing your distribution with the parameters it depends on, and then just plot those params over time? Say a gaussian distrib. is basically dependent on the sufficient parameters (mu, var). Then plot these over time

Comment: You could use a kymograph: plot the pdfs against time, with pdf intensity mapped to colour.

Comment: @BlueRineS The parameter thing I said was for example. I don't have any explicit parameter dependency. I just have a empirically obtained vector for every day which corresponds to a distribution. The dependence on parameters should be examined, I can only hypothesize.